# Why isn't my polling routine working when I poll on interrupt and works when I do on main routine

Tags: c++, microcontroller, interrupt, polling, atmega

I have a routine that polls the status of a button connected on the microcontroller ATMega328P (on chip arduino nano but code is written in C++), the routine code is this:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

bool GPIO::GetPressed()
{
     if (bit_is_clear(*this->GetPortOrPin(), this->wichPin)) 
     {
         this->confidenceReleased = 0;                         
         ++this->confidencePressed;
         if (!this->pressed && confidencePressed > thresholdPressed) 
         {
             this->pressed = true;           
             confidencePressed = 0; 
             return true;
         }
     }
    
     else 
     {
         this->confidencePressed = 0; 
         ++this->confidenceReleased;
        if (this->pressed && confidenceReleased > thresholdReleased)
        {
            this->pressed = false; 
            confidenceReleased = 0; 
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This method returns `true` if the button is pressed (it's a little bit sophisticated because there is some debouncing stuff going on), and returns `false` otherwise.

`*this->GetPortOrPin()` returns the PINX register of interest.

When I use this method inside `main` it works perfectly.

If I try to poll the button using this same method on an interrupt service routine (triggered by the button itself), this method returns always `false`.

By interrupt service routine I mean:

```
ISR (PCINTX_vect) //X can be 1 2 or 3
{
    //i press the button and code makes till this point

    if (somebutton.GetPressed() )
    {
        //never gets inside
    }
}
```

I tried to disable the interrupts once inside the ISR so maybe if the bouncing effect triggers a lot of interrupts on pin change I get rid of this problem but that didn't work.

Comment: The expression `somebutton.GetPressed` doesn't *call* the function. Please make sure you're showing us a proper [mre].

Comment: I am sorry, i fixed that. Of course that wasn't the problem

Comment: As Someprogrammerdude said, please provide a [mre], the observable reaction can be as simple as a controlled output pin. Anyway, you might want to add another output pin for debugging that signals (by toggling) where and when your method is called. I'm sure you can also reduce your example to a single button.

Comment: However, using interrupts for buttons is almost always the wrong approach. In my decades of career I found it the most effective way to use a periodic timer to poll buttons. Actually, you can omit any debouncing complexity, if you poll the buttons slower than their bounce time, commonly one to some tens of milliseconds.

Comment: I haven't read your question (too long for me) but, what is that `++this->`? (and, why do you use  `this->`? )

Comment: The method buttonpressed is about a class that represents the button, so i use this to access his own elements although it is really not necessary that should not change the behaviour

Comment: Please also format your code consistently. There are tools for that built into most IDEs. This makes the structure clearer, making the code easier to understand and debug and errors easier to find, too. Lastly, you want others to read the code, so please make it easy for them.

Comment: I formatted the code, i'm kinda new there sorry for that. I figured it out anyways but thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the code of buttonpressed method is that if you call it in the main recursively the counters will be increased in each call in the polling "fashion": if you call it on a interrupt routine the function will be executed only once and the output will always evaluate to false because the counters cannot reach threshold.